# Php script to get url of all the images in directory in json string

Tags: php, android, json, http

I already have a android app built that shows images from the server when it calls a json file which contains all the url of images.

so i want a php script to search for all the images in particular directory and then put url of all the images in json format.

my domain http://arture.16mb.com

my images dir http://arture.16mb.com/images/

**json format i currently use**

[{
    "name": "Deadpool",
    "url": {
        "small": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg",
        "medium": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg",
        "large": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg"
    },
    "timestamp": "February 12, 2016"
},
{
    "name": "Batman vs Superman",
    "url": {
        "small": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg",
        "medium": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg",
        "large": "xyzdomain/images/1.jpg"
    },
    "timestamp": "March 25, 2016"
}]

**json format which i want my php script to make**

"image": {
       "url": "//mydomain/images/....jpeg"
    },
    {
       "url": "//mydomain/images/....jpeg"
    },
    {
       "url": "//mydomain/images/....jpeg"
    }

Comment: are the images in the same server, in which your php script would be?

Comment: yes there would be a server for everything

Comment: edit your question and provide, json structure you want, directory of images and domain of your server to access the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$json = "";

foreach (glob('images/*.png') as $file){

    $json .= '{ "url":"//mydomain/'.$file.'" }, ';
}

$json = trim($json, ", ");
```

What it does, is gets all the files with `.png` extention, if you want `jpeg` files you can use `*.jpeg`
Then, all the filenames are appended to `$json`

Comment: will it put all the ulr of images in the array or filename i want json array to be like this {
 
 "url" ,"http://api.androidhive.info/images/glide/small/deadpool.jpg",
  
}

Comment: glad to have helped! :)